# how to implement multiple point data selection in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, charts, highcharts

```
 $(function () {
    var $report = $('#report');

    // create the chart
    var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
        chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            events: {
                selection: function(event) {
                    if (event.xAxis) {
                        $report.html('min: '+ event.xAxis[0].min +', max: '+ event.xAxis[0].max);
                    } else {
                        $report.html ('Selection reset');
                    }
                }
            },
            zoomType: 'x'
        },
        xAxis: {
        },

        series: [{
            data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]        
        }]
    });
});
```

This is sample code. I want to select at least two points in pin mode. It contain only zooming data after selection. In high charts there is multiple point selection available?  Pls help

Answer (score 1):

Highcharts offers multi-selection via the allowPointSelect option:

e.g. For a Column Chart:

```
var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    plotOptions: {
        column: { allowPointSelect: true }
    }
});
```

<kbd>Shift</kbd> + Left Mouse Click Or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + Left Mouse Click will multi-select points.

Examples for other chart types are available in the [Highcharts API Documentation](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions)

Comment: In any browser I've used (Mac), no combination of modifier keys allows me to select more than one point at a time. For a random example of a chart I've tried this on, see http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/series-allowpointselect-line/

Comment: Sorry, I do not have a Mac to try this out on. This works in Chrome on a Windows PC. Have you tried contacting HighCharts support - http://www.highcharts.com/support or checking their old forum which is linked to on the support page?